# jQuery .each returns only first result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This script gives me the first 'id' for every result found on click and alert. It is an ajax live result and the code returns all the right values.

Puzzling here on why the alert only shows the first record from the live result, when clicking each of them.

```
$(document).on( "click", ".result_list", function() {
    $(".result_list").each(function(){
        var mainID = $(".result_list").attr('id');
        alert(mainID);
    });
});
```

The code generated is:

```
<div class=\"result_list\" id=\"$c1-$c2-$c3\">the content per line is correct</div>
(up to X, and all with different data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses `$(this)` inside `.each()` becouse you are getting only the first item:

```
$(document).on( "click", ".result_list", function() {
        var mainID = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(mainID);
});
```

**Update:**

How you  a looking for the .result_list clicked, remove the `.each()`

Comment: Super thanks guys! But this gives alerts on all the results. I only need to store the one clicked.

Comment: Owww... Super Thanks man! I do this a lot, but just didn't focus enough. Sorry for that. Thanks for the help! All credits to all answers and answered because this was me not paying attention.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this

```
var mainID = $(".result_list").attr('id');
```

to

```
var mainID = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: Super thanks! But this gives alerts on all the results. I only need to store the one clicked. (Same result as @Wilfredo P above, actually.)